# How To make Custom Links Without Showing page not found error

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, dns

I want to make custom links to my website without showing page not found error. all links will show same webpage without redirecting.

As example my website is samplewebsite.com. i want to create custom links like samplewebsite.com/123 and that link must be show the samplewebsite.com interface without redirecting.

can i use htaccess to this ? and how ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+custom+links+OR+URL+without+redirect+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: i search on internet, but not get good result